# Save a dictionary to a file (alternative to pickle) in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, save, pickle

**Answered** I ended up going with pickle at the end anyway

Ok so with some advice on another question I asked I was told to use pickle to save a dictionary to a file.

The dictionary that I was trying to save to the file was

```
members = {'Starspy' : 'SHSN4N', 'Test' : 'Test1'}
```

When pickle saved it to the file... this was the format

```
(dp0
S'Test'
p1
S'Test1'
p2
sS'Test2'
p3
S'Test2'
p4
sS'Starspy'
p5
S'SHSN4N'
p6
s.
```

Can you please give me an alternative way to save the string to the file?

This is the format that I would like it to save in

members = {'Starspy' : 'SHSN4N', 'Test' : 'Test1'}

Complete Code:

```
import sys
import shutil
import os
import pickle

tmp = os.path.isfile("members-tmp.pkl")
if tmp == True:
    os.remove("members-tmp.pkl")
shutil.copyfile("members.pkl", "members-tmp.pkl")

pkl_file = open('members-tmp.pkl', 'rb')
members = pickle.load(pkl_file)
pkl_file.close()

def show_menu():
    os.system("clear")
    print "\n","*" * 12, "MENU", "*" * 12
    print "1. List members"
    print "2. Add member"
    print "3. Delete member"
    print "99. Save"
    print "0. Abort"
    print "*" * 28, "\n"
    return input("Please make a selection: ")

def show_members(members):
    os.system("clear")
    print "\nNames", "     ", "Code"
    for keys in members.keys():
        print keys, " - ", members[keys]

def add_member(members):
    os.system("clear")
    name = raw_input("Please enter name: ")
    code = raw_input("Please enter code: ")
    members[name] = code
    output = open('members-tmp.pkl', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(members, output)
    output.close()
    return members


#with open("foo.txt", "a") as f:
#     f.write("new line\n")

running = 1

while running:
    selection = show_menu()
    if selection == 1:
        show_members(members)
        print "\n> " ,raw_input("Press enter to continue")
    elif selection == 2:
        members == add_member(members)
        print members
        print "\n> " ,raw_input("Press enter to continue")
    elif selection == 99:
        os.system("clear")
        shutil.copyfile("members-tmp.pkl", "members.pkl")
        print "Save Completed"
        print "\n> " ,raw_input("Press enter to continue")

    elif selection == 0:
        os.remove("members-tmp.pkl")
        sys.exit("Program Aborted")
    else:
        os.system("clear")
        print "That is not a valid option!"
        print "\n> " ,raw_input("Press enter to continue")
```

Comment: What's wrong with the format? How would you like it to be?

Comment: I would like it to save as a regular dictionary E.g. members = {'Starspy' : 'SHSN4N', 'Test' : 'Test1'}

Comment: See [Storing Python dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7100125/562769)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The most common serialization format for this nowadays is JSON, which is universally supported and represents simple data structures like dictionaries very clearly.

```
>>> members = {'Starspy' : 'SHSN4N', 'Test' : 'Test1'}
>>> json.dumps(members)
'{"Test": "Test1", "Starspy": "SHSN4N"}'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(members))
{u'Test': u'Test1', u'Starspy': u'SHSN4N'}
```

Comment: Ill give it a shot. How do I specify what file to dump it to/load it from?

Comment: Dump returns a string.  You can just write this to any file as per normal python IO `with open('file.json', 'w') as f: f.write(json.dumps(members))`

Comment: @AndreasAndreou There isn't one.  The `u'Test'` format is Python, not JSON.

Comment: @watsonic No, that's a Python feature.  It's meaningless and illegal in JSON.

Comment: @GlennMaynard, try this: `type(u'foo')`. what `json.loads()` returns is a dictionary typed in unicode.

Comment: @watsonic That's the Python API.  It has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @MattClarkson: there is also `json.dump()` which writes directly to file. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33569056/1587329.

Comment: I asked this question almost 10 years ago, and have to say this is actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 60):

Sure, save it as CSV:

```
import csv
w = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
for key, val in dict.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

Then reading it would be:

```
import csv
dict = {}
for key, val in csv.reader(open("input.csv")):
    dict[key] = val
```

Another alternative would be json (`json` for version 2.6+, or install `simplejson` for 2.5 and below):

```
>>> import json
>>> dict = {"hello": "world"}
>>> json.dumps(dict)
'{"hello": "world"}'
```

Comment: Thanks, can you still import .csv files?

Comment: CSV is a very ugly suggestion.  It's used for storing tables of data, usually as exports from spreadsheets; it's not a format used for serializing data structures.

Comment: This is very true. But reading between the lines, the OP is looking to store tuples of strings in a human-friendly format… And CVS is pretty decent for that.

Comment: Actually I ran into a snag, the file that loads has an initial value of "members = {'Starspy' : 'SHSN4N', 'Test' : 'Test1'}" but after I try to add the member "Amere : MT1PN" it saves in the file as "Test1,"{'Test1': 'Test', ""members = {'Starspy' : 'SHSN4N'"": "" 'Test' : 'Test1'}""}". The result I am trying to attain is where the new dictionary saves over the old one (erases the old one) and where it can be loaded up in the program again. I am fairly new at python so I hope im making sense. Ill add the complete code for my python program as it is right now into the OP.

Comment: I got it to work, I just went with Pickle eventually and after some well termed google searches I was able to find out what I needed to do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

The YAML format (via pyyaml) might be a good option for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML

Comment: That's a great idea. The only problem is that it requires an external module.

Comment: Yep. The external dependency is a nuisance, but YAML is cute. :)

Answer (score 7):

Although, unlike `pp.pprint(the_dict)`, this won't be as pretty, will be run together, `str()` at least makes a dictionary savable in a simple way for quick tasks:

```
f.write( str( the_dict ) )
```

Comment: Since Python 3.2, this saved string object can be imported by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 3):

You [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893689/save-a-dictionary-to-a-file-alternative-to-pickle-in-python#comment5445969_4893741)

> Ill give it a shot. How do I specify what file to dump it to/load it from?

Apart from writing to a string, the `json` module provides a [`dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)-method, which writes to a file:

```
>>> a = {'hello': 'world'}
>>> import json
>>> json.dump(a, file('filename.txt', 'w'))
>>> b = json.load(file('filename.txt'))
>>> b
{u'hello': u'world'}
```

There is a `load()` method for reading, too.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd suggest `pickle`, if you want an alternative, you can use `klepto`.

```
>>> init = {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> import klepto
>>> cache = klepto.archives.file_archive('memo', init, serialized=False)
>>> cache        
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>>
>>> # dump dictionary to the file 'memo.py'
>>> cache.dump() 
>>> 
>>> # import from 'memo.py'
>>> from memo import memo
>>> print memo
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

With `klepto`, if you had used `serialized=True`, the dictionary would have been written to `memo.pkl` as a pickled dictionary instead of with clear text.

You can get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto

`dill` is probably a better choice for pickling then `pickle` itself, as `dill` can serialize almost anything in python.  `klepto` also can use `dill`.

You can get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill