# Storing Python dictionaries

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, persistence

Are there simple ways to store a dictionary (or multiple dictionaries) in, for example, a JSON or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) file?

For example, if I have some data like:

```
data = {}
data ['key1'] = "keyinfo"
data ['key2'] = "keyinfo2"
```

How can I save it in a file, and then later load it back in to the program from the file?

---

<sub>JSON and Pickle can also be used to store more complex structured data. This question may also include answers that are specific to the case of a simple dictionary like the one described. For more general approaches, see [How can I write structured data to a file and then read it back into the same structure later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890485/). Note that the technique of converting the data to storable data is called *serialization*, and re-creating the data structure is called *deserialization*; storing the data for later use is called *persistence*.</sub>

<sub>See also [What do files actually contain, and how are they "read"? What is a "format" and why should I worry about them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078605/) for some theory about how files work, and why structured data cannot just be written into and read from files directly.</sub>

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) standard modules?

Comment: See [Save a dictionary to a file (alternative to pickle) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4893689/562769)

Comment: This is a special case of [How can I write structured data to a file and then read it back into the same structure later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890485/).

Answer (score 624, accepted):

**[Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) save:**

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:  # Python 3.x
    import pickle

with open('data.p', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(data, fp, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

See [the pickle module documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) for additional information regarding the `protocol` argument.

**[Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) load:**

```
with open('data.p', 'rb') as fp:
    data = pickle.load(fp)
```

---

**[JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) save:**

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

Supply extra arguments, like `sort_keys` or `indent`, to get a pretty result. The argument *sort_keys* will sort the keys alphabetically and *indent* will indent your data structure with `indent=N` spaces.

```
json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

**[JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) load:**

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```

Comment: JSON does dictionaries natively (though they obviously don't behave exactly as a python dictionary does while in memory, for persistence purposes, they are identical). In fact, the foundational unit in json is the "Object", which is defined as { <string> : <value>}. Look familiar? The json module in the standard library supports every Python native type and can easily be extended with a minimal knowledge of json to support user-defined classes. [The JSON homepage](http://www.json.org/) completely defines the language in just over 3 printed pages, so it's easy to absorb/digest quickly.

Comment: It's worth knowing about the third argument to `pickle.dump`, too. If the file doesn't need to be human-readable then it can speed things up a lot.

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work out-of-the-box with 3.x. Which part has to be casted?

Comment: Why are you using binary mode for the JSON files here? JSON is a text format.

Comment: @Dror: The `json` library produces text (type `str`) data, so the files should not be opened in binary mode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, and Dror: I'm fairly certain that was a poorly executed copy and paste. Fixed in the most recent edit, thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: If you add **sort_keys** and **indent** arguments to the dump call you get a much prettier result. e.g.: `json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`. More info can be found  [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: You should probably use `pickle.dump(data, fp, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

Comment: @Marty - Is there any advantage of using `pickle` vs `json`?  `json` is a readable file instead of a byte stream; size of resulting file, etc?

Comment: @Matteo Json won't work with dict that have tuples as keys { (1,2): "abc" }, but they are readable by people. Pickle will save dicts that have tuples as keys, but they are not as readble by people as Json.

Comment: For python 3, use `import pickle`

Comment: Is it only me or is saving the json really slow? Trying to store approx 100mb json.

Comment: There are multiple ways of importing a dictionary. Importing variable from different file, using json, and using pickle. What are the differences?

Comment: I've tried to check which is better in memory usage, for me pickle was 5 kb and json was 15 kb. If it helps anyone.

Comment: Wrt to pickle, it's a pretty sad state of affairs that the word `security` does not appear anywhere in this page.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183966/safely-load-a-pickle-file

Comment: note : You cannot use the json method for saving dictionary object multiple times, since `w` is used for opening the file and it will  overwrite the contents  with new content every time those lines are executed (same goes for pickle i guess, didn't really tried that one)

Comment: @VineeshTP maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351352/7500651) will help

Comment: @anshsachdeva  JSON.stringify(result_dict, null, 2);  '2' worked for me.

Answer (score 53):

Minimal example, writing directly to a file:

```
import json
json.dump(data, open(filename, 'wb'))
data = json.load(open(filename))
```

or safely opening / closing:

```
import json
with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
with open(filename) as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

If you want to save it in a string instead of a file:

```
import json
json_str = json.dumps(data)
data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Answer (score 9):

Also see the speeded-up package [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson):

```
import ujson

with open('data.json', 'wb') as fp:
    ujson.dump(data, fp)
```

Comment: Does this package do all what json does? I mean is it fully replaceable with json all the time?

Comment: How often is serialization the bottleneck, when we must write to file anyway?

Answer (score 7):

To write to a file:

```
import json
myfile.write(json.dumps(mydict))
```

To read from a file:

```
import json
mydict = json.loads(myfile.read())
```

`myfile` is the file object for the file that you stored the dict in.

Comment: you are ware that json has that take files as arguments and write directly to them?

Comment: `json.dump(myfile)` and `json.load(myfile)`

Answer (score 7):

If you want an alternative to `pickle` or `json`, you can use `klepto`.

```
>>> init = {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>> import klepto
>>> cache = klepto.archives.file_archive('memo', init, serialized=False)
>>> cache        
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
>>>
>>> # dump dictionary to the file 'memo.py'
>>> cache.dump() 
>>> 
>>> # import from 'memo.py'
>>> from memo import memo
>>> print memo
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

With `klepto`, if you had used `serialized=True`, the dictionary would have been written to `memo.pkl` as a pickled dictionary instead of with clear text.

You can get `klepto` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto

`dill` is probably a better choice for pickling then `pickle` itself, as `dill` can serialize almost anything in python.  `klepto` also can use `dill`.

You can get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill

The additional mumbo-jumbo on the first few lines are because `klepto` can be configured to store dictionaries to a file, to a directory context, or to a SQL database.  The API is the same for whatever you choose as the backend archive.  It gives you an "archivable" dictionary with which you can use `load` and `dump` to interact with the archive.

Answer (score 6):

If you're after serialization, but won't need the data in other programs, I strongly recommend the `shelve` module. Think of it as a persistent dictionary.

```
myData = shelve.open('/path/to/file')

# Check for values.
keyVar in myData

# Set values
myData[anotherKey] = someValue

# Save the data for future use.
myData.close()
```

Comment: If you want to store a whole dict, or load a whole dict, `json` is more convenient. `shelve` is only better for accessing one key at a time.

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between pickle and shelve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103430/)

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, we should include ConfigParser and configparser which are part of the standard library in Python 2 and 3, respectively. This module reads and writes to a config/ini file and (at least in Python 3) behaves in a lot of ways like a dictionary. It has the added benefit that you can store multiple dictionaries into separate sections of your config/ini file and recall them. Sweet!

Python 2.7.x example.

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

dict1 = {'key1':'keyinfo', 'key2':'keyinfo2'}
dict2 = {'k1':'hot', 'k2':'cross', 'k3':'buns'}
dict3 = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}

# Make each dictionary a separate section in the configuration
config.add_section('dict1')
for key in dict1.keys():
    config.set('dict1', key, dict1[key])
   
config.add_section('dict2')
for key in dict2.keys():
    config.set('dict2', key, dict2[key])

config.add_section('dict3')
for key in dict3.keys():
    config.set('dict3', key, dict3[key])

# Save the configuration to a file
f = open('config.ini', 'w')
config.write(f)
f.close()

# Read the configuration from a file
config2 = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config2.read('config.ini')

dictA = {}
for item in config2.items('dict1'):
    dictA[item[0]] = item[1]

dictB = {}
for item in config2.items('dict2'):
    dictB[item[0]] = item[1]

dictC = {}
for item in config2.items('dict3'):
    dictC[item[0]] = item[1]

print(dictA)
print(dictB)
print(dictC)
```

Python 3.X example.

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

dict1 = {'key1':'keyinfo', 'key2':'keyinfo2'}
dict2 = {'k1':'hot', 'k2':'cross', 'k3':'buns'}
dict3 = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}

# Make each dictionary a separate section in the configuration
config['dict1'] = dict1
config['dict2'] = dict2
config['dict3'] = dict3

# Save the configuration to a file
f = open('config.ini', 'w')
config.write(f)
f.close()

# Read the configuration from a file
config2 = configparser.ConfigParser()
config2.read('config.ini')

# ConfigParser objects are a lot like dictionaries, but if you really
# want a dictionary you can ask it to convert a section to a dictionary
dictA = dict(config2['dict1'] )
dictB = dict(config2['dict2'] )
dictC = dict(config2['dict3'])

print(dictA)
print(dictB)
print(dictC)
```

#### Console output

```
{'key2': 'keyinfo2', 'key1': 'keyinfo'}
{'k1': 'hot', 'k2': 'cross', 'k3': 'buns'}
{'z': '3', 'y': '2', 'x': '1'}
```

#### Contents of config.ini

```
[dict1]
key2 = keyinfo2
key1 = keyinfo

[dict2]
k1 = hot
k2 = cross
k3 = buns

[dict3]
z = 3
y = 2
x = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If save to a JSON file, the best and easiest way of doing this is:

```
import json
with open("file.json", "wb") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dict).encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: why is this easier than `json.dump( )` as outlined in the other answer?

Comment: @baxx The answer for your question probably is file writing mode (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860227/5595995)

Comment: @CloudCho that argument is no good in 3.x, because the file used with `json.dump` can simply be a file open in text mode with an appropriate `encoding` chosen when it's opened. (Aside from that, using any encoding other than UTF-8 for JSON [is nonstandard and unacceptable for open ecosystems](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Do you mean we need proper "encoding" option? Regarding your link, I don't see related to UTF-8...please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

My use case was to save multiple JSON objects to a file and [marty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries/7100202#7100202) helped me somewhat. But to serve my use case, the answer was not complete as it would overwrite the old data every time a new entry was saved.

To save multiple entries in a file, one must check for the old content (i.e., read before write). A typical file holding JSON data will either have a `list` or an `object` as root. So I considered that my JSON file always has a `list of objects` and every time I add data to it, I simply load the list first, append my new data in it, and dump it back to a writable-only instance of file (`w`):

```py
def saveJson(url,sc): # This function writes the two values to the file
    newdata = {'url':url,'sc':sc}
    json_path = "db/file.json"

    old_list= []
    with open(json_path) as myfile:  # Read the contents first
        old_list = json.load(myfile)
    old_list.append(newdata)

    with open(json_path,"w") as myfile:  # Overwrite the whole content
        json.dump(old_list, myfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    return "success"
```

The new JSON file will look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "sc": "a11",
        "url": "www.google.com"
    },
    {
        "sc": "a12",
        "url": "www.google.com"
    },
    {
        "sc": "a13",
        "url": "www.google.com"
    }
]
```

**NOTE:** It is essential to have a file named `file.json` with `[]` as initial data for this approach to work

PS: not related to original question, but this approach could also be further improved by first checking if our entry already exists (based on one or multiple keys) and only then append and save the data.