# How to transform an array to json object in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I would like to tranform an array to on object .

```
I have an array : ['BROOKLYN','STATEN ISLAND','OZONE PARK','SOUTH OZONE PARK', 'JAMAICA','OZONE PARK']
```

I am going to transofrm it to json object adding ":red" prefix .

```
colormap = {'NEW YORK': 'red', 'BROOKLYN': 'red', 'STATEN ISLAND': 'red', 'OZONE PARK':'red','SOUTH OZONE PARK':'red', 'JAMAICA':'red','OZONE PARK': 'red'}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: It looks like you want to convert a list to a dictionary. How does this have anything to do with JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `fromkeys` method in the dictionary, like this

   ```
   print {}.fromkeys(myArray, "set")
   ```
2. Or you can use `zip` like this

   ```
   print dict(zip(myArray, ["set"] * len(myArray)))
   ```

**Output**

```
{'OZONE PARK': 'set', 'BROOKLYN': 'set', 'STATEN ISLAND': 'set', 'SOUTH OZONE PARK': 'set', 'JAMAICA': 'set'}
```

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` seems like it would be the right way. (`{}.fromkeys` doesn’t have a lot of meaning.) But why bother with `zip` at all?

Comment: `dict.fromkeys` is ideal since the value is immutable. The version with zip...why would you ruin a good answer with that?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to create a dict from your list. If so, you can do it like this:

```
colormap = {x:'red' for x in myList}
```

Afterwards, you can save it in json format using json module (please see a relevant question [Storing Python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries) and [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)).

Comment: Thanks ! What is the best way to save it to json object (.to_JSON() )

Comment: @user3001937 Please check out the edit for json info (has been asked a few times before - you can search other similar questions).

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

array = ["test", "test1", "test2"]

colors = {item: "red" for item in array}

json_str_colors = json.dumps(colors)

print(repr(json_str_colors))
```