# Save a python 3.x dictionary to JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7100202/671013) allows saving a `dict` into `json`. For instance:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'wb') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

However, this doesn't work with `3.x`. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface), the solution is some sort of cast; but I don't manage to do it for a dictionary. What's the right way to save a `dict` to `json` using python 3.x?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

remove the `b`:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```

[json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dump)

*The json module always produces str objects, not bytes objects. Therefore, fp.write() must support str input.*

Comment: Can you please add some reference? Where could I find this solution in the documentation?