# How do I store an arbitrary dictionary to a file so that it can be read in Fortran as well?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

Let's say we have a dictionary

```
import numpy as np
d={}
d["s0"]=3
d["s1"]=np.int16(3)
d["s2"]=np.array("hello")
d["s3"]=np.array([2])
d["s4"]=np.linspace(0,2, 3)
```

One way to save this dictionary is to use json. Which means serializing and storing the data as a list. In this case there can be loss of precision.

Another way is to convert this into a pandas DataFrame and save that to hdf:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
#dd.io.save("test.h5", d)
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
store["data"]=df
```

But this failed. I get:

```
  ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

A yet third way is to use deepdish:

```
dd.io.save("test.h5", d)
```

The problem with this method was it wants my keys to be strings and misses key data without throwing up error:

```
    $h5ls test.h5
    s3                       Dataset {1}
    s4                       Dataset {3}
```

Note that "s0", "s1" and "s2" were not saved to the file and no error was reported. So what is the safest way to store a python dictionary to an hdf file?

I don't want to use pickle dump because it will be hard to read back in Fortran. This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries) because it shown how those methods failed to store needed data.

Comment: Use `pd.Series` instead of `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: I have already covered various option so it is not a duplicate. I have shown how various answers failed.

Comment: I think `pickle` is the best option in this case...

Comment: Can't read `pickle` in fortran

Comment: With `h5py` you can save dictionaries and arrays.  The `h5` groups are dictionary like, but limited to string keys.  The datasets are numpy array like.  While Python dictionaries can use any `hashable` as keys, it will hard to translate that across languages. While I've used Fortran on and off over many decades, I don't know what dictionary like data structures are available.  Best stick with structures implemented by widely used file formats.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't a cutting-edge answer that will impress any uber-geeks, but if you need portability, I'd suggest an INI file. There isn't a language or platform in existence that can't read or write it.

Here's a FORTRAN library for handling them.

https://github.com/szaghi/FiNeR