# Save a Python dictionary in JSON format

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some data in the following variables,

want to store the python dictionary in the following JSON format,

```
{
  'name': {
  'Address': '123 abc, IN, 50012',
  'Phone': '123456',
  },
  'name2': {
  'Address': '123 abc, IN, 50012',
  'Phone': '123456',
  },
}
```

Updated JSON format(Required in this format)

```
{
  "name":[
  {"Address": "123 abc, IN, 50012"},
  {"Phone": "123456"}
  ],
  "name2": [
  {"Address": "123 abc, IN, 50012"},
  {"Phone": "123456"}
  ]
}
```

But I managed only to get the JSON in this format,

```
{"phone": "123456738", "address": "address1,", "name": "name1"}
{"phone": "123456178", "address": "address2,", "name": "name2"}
{"phone": "123452678", "address": "address3,", "name": "name3"}
```

below is my code

```
#getting data and adding to dict
dict_list = []
for data in all_data:
    dict = {}
    dict["phone"] = phone.strip()
    dict["address"] = address.strip()
    dict["name"] = name.strip()
    dict_list.append(dict)

#writing to json file
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
  for details in dict_list:
    r = json.dumps(details)
    loaded_r = json.loads(r)
    json.dump(loaded_r, outfile)
```

Comment: The Json you are trying to achieve is not valid(not in correct format)

Comment: comment above is right: there's an extra comma that json doesn't accept. BTW you mean to use `indent` parameter?

Comment: You should use the JSON library instead of trying to do this manually. Check out this link from the python documentation - https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have updated the required JSON format

Comment: @Nick am uisng that JSON library already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

you want to convert the inner dictionary to a list of dictionaries containing only one key & value. Doable with some comprehension syntax:

```
in_dict = {
  'name': {
  'Address': '123 abc, IN, 50012',
  'Phone': '123456',
  },
  'name2': {
  'Address': '123 abc, IN, 50012',
  'Phone': '123456',
  },
}

out_dict = {k : [{k2:v2} for k2,v2 in v.items()] for k,v in in_dict.items()}
```

For each key,value (dictionary) pair, iterate on items of the sub-dict and create 1 dictionary per key,value in a `list`.

result:

```
>>> out_dict
{'name': [{'Address': '123 abc, IN, 50012'}, {'Phone': '123456'}],
 'name2': [{'Address': '123 abc, IN, 50012'}, {'Phone': '123456'}]}
```