# How to iterate list items to store as a dictionary and write it to json?

Tags: python, json

I have a list and I want to iterate and write it to write to json.
For example:

```
lis_1 = ['fellow','hello','yellow']
```

Now I store it as a dictionary:

```
items_main = {}
new_list = []
result_2 = {}
items = {}
lis_1 = ['fellow','hello','yellow']
for i,l in enumerate(lis_1):
    key, value = str(i+1), str(lis_1[i])
    items[key] = value
    new_list.append(items)

for d in new_list:
    result_2.update(d)
print(result_2)
```

I am also few other variable to the same

```
name = 'buddy'
year = 2008

sample = {    
    "FDRID1":{
         "1": {
            "Property_name":{ 
              "1": str(name )
               },

             items_main['Building Highlights'] = result_2

              "Year":{
                  "1":str(year)
                     }
                }
             }
        }

with open(out_file, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(sample, fp)
```

Expected output:

```
"FDRID1":{
          "1": {
         "Property_name":{ 
              "1": "buddy"
               },

          "BuildingHighlights":{
               "1":"fellow",
               "2":"hello",
               "3":"yellow"
                  },
        "Year":{
             "1":'2008'
                }
       }
  }
```

Also if the **lis_1 = ['']**i.e., (empty).The output must be:

```
"FDRID1":{
              "1": {
             "Property_name":{ 
                  "1": "buddy"
                   },

              "BuildingHighlights":{
                   "1":"",
                   "
                      },
            "Year":{
                 "1":'2008'
                    }
           }
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries)

Comment: Is there any reason you are creating the list of dictionaries then merging the list of dicts into a dict?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I've understood exactly what you are trying to do:

```
result_1 = {str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(lis_1, 1)} if lis_1 else {'1', ''}
```

Your example output for the empty list isn't valid json because it has a spurious `"` - assuming this is just an editing error.