# Python 2 - iterating through csv with determinating specific lines as dicitonary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key, key-value

I generated csv from multiple dictionaries (to be readable and editable too) with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893689/save-a-dictionary-to-a-file-alternative-to-pickle-in-python) question. Output is simple

```
//Dictionary
key,value
key2,value2
//Dictionary2
key4, value4
key5, value5
```

i want double backslash to be separator to create new dictionary, but every calling csv.reader(open("input.csv")) evaluates through lines so i have no use of:

```
import csv
dict = {}
for key, val in csv.reader(open("input.csv")):
    dict[key] = val
```

Thanks for helping me out..

Edit: i made this piece of.. well "code".. I'll be glad if you can check it out and review:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv

# list of dictionaries 
l = []

# evalute throught csv
for row in csv.reader(open("test.csv")):

    if row[0].startswith("//"):

        # stripped "//" line is name for dictionary
        n = row[0][2:]

        # append stripped "//" line as name for dictionary

        #debug
        print n

        l.append(n)
        #debug print l[:]

    elif len(row) == 2:

        # debug
        print "len(row) %s" % len(row)
        # debug
        print "row[:] %s" % row[:]

        for key, val in row:
            # print key,val
            l[-1] = dic
            dic = {}
            dic[key] = val
# debug
for d in l:
    print l
    for key, value in d:
        print key, value
```

unfortunately i got this Error:

```
DictName
len(row) 2
row[:] ['key', ' value']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reader.py", line 31, in <module>
    for key, val in row:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even attempt to make multiple dictionaries or look for `'//Dictionary'`, so why would you expect any different? Think about iterating over the file; what are the two cases for each line and what should you do in each?

Comment: thank you very much @jonrsharpe, ill update with original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Consider not using CSV

First of all, your overall strategy to the data problem is probably not optimal. The less tabular your data looks, the less sense it makes to keep it in a CSV file (though your needs aren't too far out of the realm).

For example, it would be really easy to solve this problem using json:

```
import json

# First the data
data = dict(dict1=dict(key1="value1", key2="value2"),
            dict2=dict(key3="value3", key4="value4"))

# Convert and write
js = json.dumps(data)
f = file("data.json", 'w')
f.write(js)
f.close()

# Now read back
f = file("data.json", 'r')
data = json.load(f)
print data
```

### Answering the question as written

However, if you are *really* set on this strategy, you can do something along the lines suggested by jonrsharpe. You can't just use the `csv` module to do all the work for you, but actually have to go through and filter out (and split by) the "//" lines.

```
import csv
import re

def header_matcher(line):
    "Returns something truthy if the line looks like a dict separator"
    return re.match("//", line)


# Open the file and ...
f = open("data.csv")
# create some containers we can populate as we iterate
data = []
d = {}

for line in f:
    if not header_matcher(line):
        # We have a non-header row, so we make a new entry in our draft dictionary
        key, val = line.strip().split(',')
        d[key] = val
    else:
        # We've hit a new header, so we should throw our draft dictionary in our data list
        if d:
            # ... but only if we actually have had data since the last header
            data.append(d)
            d = {}
# The very last chunk will need to be captured as well
if d:
    data.append(d)

# And we're done...
print data
```

This is quite a bit messier, and if there is any chance of needed to escape commas, it will get messier still. If you needed, you could probably find a clever way of chunking up the file into generators that you read with CSV readers, but it won't be particularly clean/easy (I started an approach like this but it looked like pain...). This is all a testament to your approach likely being the wrong way to store this data.

### An alternative if you're set on CSV

Another way to go if you really want CSV but aren't stuck on the exact data format you specify: Add a column in the CSV file corresponding to the dictionary the data should go into. Imagine a file (`data2.csv`) that looks like this:

```
dict1,key1,value1
dict1,key2,value2
dict2,key3,value3
dict2,key4,value4
```

Now we can do something cleaner, like the following:

```
import csv

data = dict()
for chunk, key, val in csv.reader(file('test2.csv')):
    try:
        # If we already have a dict for the given chunk id, this should add the key/value pair
        data[chunk][key] = val
    except KeyError:
        # Otherwise, we catch the exception and add a fresh dictionary with the key/value pair
        data[chunk] = {key: val}

print data
```

Much nicer...

The only good argument for doing something closer to what you have in mind over this is if there is LOTS of data, and space is a concern. But that is not very likely to be case in most situations.

### And pandas

Oh yes... one more possible solution is pandas. I haven't used it much yet, so I'm not as much help, but there is something along the lines of a `group_by` function it provides, which would let you group by the first column if you end up structuring the data as in the the 3-column CSV approach.

Comment: Well thank you very much! As long as I will only be the one to edit "datafile" which contains keys and values, json should be fine, but as a beginner, from what i heard, csv is fine readable and so other users willing to change dictionaries will be. So Ill stick to harder way and filtering. After hours (for me coding is real struggle) i came up with something similar (not that clean) as you did at your second example, i edited it to my post and looking forward to try yours tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah; CSV is really nice for quite a number of reasons (check out the csvkit command line utils if you haven't already), so I use it quite often. Json is still pretty readable as far as more flexible text formats go though, and in many cases can represent the actual structure of the data much more cleanly (making it ultimately easier to edit), but it really depends on the situation. Still, do consider the third way if you really want to stick to CSV. Also, I recommend posting the solution you came up with as an answer, so others can review and comment on it separately from the question itself.

Comment: Begginer's mistake, it wont happen again, i promise :) I'll try both codes and update my solution. Json way and CSV. I'm afraid third one does not meet my need, but it won't prevent me from experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

## I decided to use json instead

Reading this is easier for the program and there's no need to filter text. For generating the data inside database in external `file.json` will serve python program.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import json

category1 = {"server name1":"ip address1","server name2":"ip address2"}

category2 = {"server name1":"ip address1","server name1":"ip address1"}

servers = { "category Alias1":category1,"category Alias2":category2}

js = json.dumps(servers)
f = file("servers.json", "w")
f.write(js)
f.close()

# Now read back
f = file("servers.json", "r")
data = json.load(f)
print data
```

So the output is dictionary containing keys for categories and as values are another dictionaries. Exactly as i wanted.