# pickle a dictonary in python in a readable format

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

#### Given

I have a python dictionary in a file in a format like shown below
and I want to read it back.

Fromat A:

```
(dp0
S'Test'
p1
S'Test1'
p2
sS'Test2'
p3
S'Test2'
p4
sS'Starspy'
p5
S'SHSN4N'
p6
s.
```

The file contents has been created saving it with pickle, see
[Save a dictionary to a file (alternative to pickle) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893689/save-a-dictionary-to-a-file-alternative-to-pickle-in-python).

#### Issue

When I try to save a dictionary with pickle the format that I obtain does not correspond.

For example, the code:

```
import pickle
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
output = open('myfile.dict', 'wb')
pickle.dump(mydict, output)
output.close()
```

produces a file with following content (Format B):

```
€}q (X   aqKX   bqKX   cqKu.
```

I can read it back OK, but it has not the format of my file (that correspond to a nested dictionary).

#### Questions

I have two questions:

1. How can I write a file with the given format (Format A) ?
2. How can I read a file with that format?

Comment: If you want a human-readable version, why not use JSON instead?

Answer (score 2):

The question is answered in the `pickle` module documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format

> There are currently 3 different protocols which can be used for
>   pickling.
>
> Protocol version 0 is the original ASCII protocol and is backwards
>   compatible with earlier versions of Python.
>
> Protocol version 1 is the
>   old binary format which is also compatible with earlier versions of
>   Python.
>
> Protocol version 2 was introduced in Python 2.3. It provides
>   much more efficient pickling of new-style classes.

Whatever you show in the beginning, it the protocol version 0, and is the default. In the end — the binary protocol versions 1 or 2.

Just specify the protocol version number:

```
>>> pickle.dump({'hello': 'world'}, file('f.txt', 'wt'))
>>> file('f.txt', 'rt').read()
"(dp0\nS'hello'\np1\nS'world'\np2\ns."

>>> pickle.dump({'hello': 'world'}, file('f.txt', 'wt'), 2)
>>> file('f.txt', 'rt').read()
'\x80\x02}q\x00U\x05helloq\x01U\x05worldq\x02s.'

>>> pickle.dump({'hello': 'world'}, file('f.txt', 'wt'), 1)
>>> file('f.txt', 'rt').read()
'}q\x00U\x05helloq\x01U\x05worldq\x02s.'
```

PS: Why not just use a readable format, e.g. json?

Answer (score 2):

If you want readable dictionaries then go with [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) it built into python and the output is pretty much like a dictionary.

Comment: I am sorry, your code does not work in my computer. It gives me an error. My problem is that I have a large file with a nested dictionary with many layers that someone pass to me (so I cannot save the data in a different format) and the file is in the format  (dp0 S'Test' p1 S'Test1' p2 sS'Test2' p3 S'Test2' p4 sS'Starspy' p5 S'SHSN4N' p6 s. That is the reason I want to: 1) to learn how I can save a file with that kind of format and 2) mainly to be able to open the file I have.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I have was a problem of versions. I was using version 3 and it works with version 2.

In that case, I can create a file with the format I have in the file I want to read, and I can now read it.